# How do I optimize this FormatAccountNumber method?

Tags: c#

I've written this method for formatting Account number:

```cs
public static  string FormatAccountNumber(string accountNumber)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountNumber))
        return string.Empty;

    if (accountNumber.Length < 4)
        return "****";
    else
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int starLength = accountNumber.Length - 4;

        for (int index = 0; index < starLength; index++)
            stringBuilder.Append("*");

        stringBuilder.Append(accountNumber.Substring(accountNumber.Length - 4));

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Can this optimized or is it already optimized by use of `StringBuilder`?

Comment: What kind of optimisation are you looking for and why? Min. lines of code, min. execution time, max. readability, compliance with coding standards, something else?

Comment: @Daniel: Min execution time. I do not mind if lines are not minimum.

Comment: Rather than than `for` loop you can use a string's constructor. `stringBuilder.Append(new string('*', starLength))` But the execution time of this is already going to be pretty fast. Seems like you are trying to optimize something that doesn't need to be optimized.

Comment: Ok, why do you want to min. execution time? Do you have evidence that this function is causing a runtime performance issue?

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw: No. I just want to know if there is any better way of peforming this **maybe** using some built in function of string class.

Comment: Smells of Premature Optimisation: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization. I'd suggest focusing on "simpler" rather than "faster". Simpler things tend to be easier to understand now and in the future (usually far more important than runtime performance) and, often, end up being faster as a happy side effect.

Comment: @VCSJones: Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method below does what you need, is easy to read and executes several times faster. Still if you don't need to execute it thousands times, you want see the execution time difference.

```
    public static string FormatAccountNumber2(string accountNumber)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountNumber))
            return string.Empty;

        if (accountNumber.Length < 4)
            return "****";

        return new string('*', accountNumber.Length - 4) +
            accountNumber.Substring(accountNumber.Length - 4);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test this with my method. If this performs better in terms of execution speed, I will select it as answer. Actually I have a datagrid with 100's of records and this method will be fired for each of the row.

Comment: wow, your method actually took less! Thanks. I tested it on 100000 items. Mine took 86ms. Yours took 29ms.